# How to receive logs of my app from device

Tags: ios, xcode

I am Logging the messages using os_log, i can see the logs on console app while device is attached with Xcode in debug environment.

But i want to fetch the logs of my app from the device when it is not attached with Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the device log using sysDiagnose.

You can Press and hold both volume buttons and side button for 1.0 to 1.5 seconds, then release.

[image]

Once sysDiagnose is triggered, you can find the logs from

```
 Settings >   Privacy > Analytics & Improvements > Analytics Data
```

**Note:** SysDiagnose will give you the all logs from device, you will have to apply filters for your apps subsystems and categories to get logs specific to your app.